# Importing .doc and .jpg files to 13.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, files

I'm a new user - not familiar with the limitations or options available with partitioned hard drives. I just installed 13.04 on a partitioned hard drive to dual boot with Windows 7. Now I want to import .doc and .jpg files from an external drive into Ubuntu.

Will I be able to access these files on the Windows side of the partition and vice versa? If I create something using MS Office, or other Windows software, will I be able to access the file in Ubuntu?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### Yes.

There is almost always an alternative to windows programs. Documents and images are handled well by the default programs, Libre Office and Image viewer respectively.

You will be able to access windows partition from within Ubuntu, however, windows refuses to recognize the ubuntu partition. If you would like to access files from both windows and Ubuntu, it is recommended to make a third partition in NTFS or FAT and store your files there.

Comment: Thank you Mahesh. Yes, I have learned that Windows will not recognize the Ubuntu partition I created when installing Ubuntu. In order to create an NTFS partition, do I need to delete the Ubuntu partition and use Windows to create the new one?

Comment: You will need a separate third partition for data besides the ones with Ubuntu and Windows. Strictly speaking, you can have all data in Windows partition, but it is always a good practice to keep data and operating system separate. You can boot from a live usb and use `gparted` to resize the existing partitions to make space and create a new NTFS volume.

Comment: Thanks, it worked great! I used Windows disk manager to create the partition but I also practiced with Gparted and learned how to create an NTFS partition. Thank you again, your suggestion was very helpful!